# How to delete a column of a single row in Google Cloud Bigtable with HBase API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm using the HBase API to access Google Cloud Bigtable, but whenever I try to delete a column:

```
Delete delete = new Delete(r.getRow());
delete.addColumn(CF, Bytes.toBytes(d.seqid()));
delete.addColumn(CF, COL_LEASE);
tasksTable.delete(delete);
```

I'm getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot delete single latest cell.
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.DeleteAdapter.throwIfUnsupportedPointDelete(DeleteAdapter.java:85)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.DeleteAdapter.adapt(DeleteAdapter.java:141)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.HBaseRequestAdapter.adapt(HBaseRequestAdapter.java:71)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableTable.delete(BigtableTable.java:307)
at queue.BigTableRowBackedQueue.poll(BigTableRowBackedQueue.java:54)
```

I saw in the [code it occurs here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/948899d6be58b3a560a3eac6e2e2f485054cb5eb/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/DeleteAdapter.java#L88).

I can delete the entire row fine from the HBase Java client, and I can delete individual columns fine by using the HBase shell.

How can I delete columns without removing the row in the Java client?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry for your troubles.  Bigtable and HBase differ in a couple of ways, and this is one of them.

```
Delete delete = new Delete(rowKey);
delete.addColumns(COLUMN_FAMILY, qual); // the 's' matters
table.delete(delete);
```

HBase's `Delete.addColumn` deletes only the latest cell from the column.  The `Delete.addColumn_s_` means delete all cells (i.e. all the various timestamps).  Alternatively, you can delete a specific cell via `Delete.addColumn(byte[], byte[], long)` where the `long` is a timestamp.

The hbase shell delete [uses](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/1.1.6/hbase-shell/src/main/ruby/hbase/table.rb#L196) `deleteColumns` which maps to `addColumns` under the cover.  It also uses the `s` variation, which is why it works.

For reference [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase-integration-tests/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/TestDelete.java) is our complete TestDelete suite which identify the use case you present as `@Category(KnownGap.class)` which we use to identify differences missing HBase features in the Bigtable client.