# Java: Cannot perform column family deletion at timestamp.HBASE api

Tags: java, hbase, unsupportedoperation

```
Delete delete = new Delete(Bytes.toBytes("hello#2"),1585990109000l);
delete.addFamilyVersion(Bytes.toBytes("gretting"), 1585990109000l);
Table table;
try{table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
    table.delete(delete);
    deleted =true;  
    LOG.info("deleted");
    table.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {                     
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot perform column family deletion at timestamp.
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.DeleteAdapter.throwOnUnsupportedDeleteFamilyVersion(DeleteAdapter.java:66) ~[bigtable-hbase-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.DeleteAdapter.adaptMutations(DeleteAdapter.java:160) ~[bigtable-hbase-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.DeleteAdapter.adaptMutations(DeleteAdapter.java:43) ~[bigtable-hbase-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.MutationAdapter.adapt(MutationAdapter.java:48) ~[bigtable-hbase-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.adapters.HBaseRequestAdapter.adapt(HBaseRequestAdapter.java:125) ~[bigtable-hbase-1.6.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: check this github example [delete column family](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigtable/src/main/java/com/m/examples/bigtable/TableAdminExample.java#L357) and [delete a column of a single row in Google Cloud Bigtable with HBase API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650460/how-to-delete-a-column-of-a-single-row-in-google-cloud-bigtable-with-hbase-api/39668917)

Comment: Me funcionó con tu ayuda @josepraveen